# Haskell check if chess board diagonal movement is True or False

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a board game function of 4x5 board and I want to do a simple true false Bool function stating if the movement based on x,y coordinates is diagonal or not. I want to put 4 coordinates 2 x and 2 y. should I use the && function if for example I want to put (1,1) and (2,2)?

```
 isDiagonal x  
 if x == 1 && y == 1 then True
 else False
 isDiagonal x
 if x == 2 && y == 2 then True 
 else False
```

Comment: This is  unclear. The code above is meaningless, and I can't understand the description of the task. I'd suggest you start to write the _type_ for your function. What is the input type? (Only one argument `x`? what about `y`?) What is the return type ? (`Bool` ?) Saying a "simple true false Bool function" does not tell much. Perhaps you want `isDiagonal x y = x==y` but it's hard to tell. Again: don't write anything until you have decided its type.

Comment: For what it's worth, I disagree with @chi: it's very clear to me what function you want to write. But the rest of the question sucks anyway: StackOverflow is neither a code-writing service nor a tutorial recommendation service (so I voted to close as "too broad"). Google can find you a tutorial; and a bit of pencil-and-paper work can help you cook up an algorithm. Once you have those things you'll be able to make an attempt at writing some code, and *then* if your code does not work the way you want it to you may have a more targeted, on-topic question for this site.

Comment: @DanielWagner I did not vote to close (even if I considered that), since I thought this could be a small task. Now, seeing the answer below, and rereading the question, I can finally see what it was about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a point `(x,y)`  is on the same diagonal as a point `(x',y')` in Haskell, a good place to start is with a type.

```
isDiagonal :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Bool
```

Whilst technically optional, it's good practice to give every top level function an explicit type.

Now, we need a body for this function.

```
isDiagonal (x, y) (x', y') = ...
```

If they're on the same diagonal, then `x` and `x'` must be as far apart from each other as `y` and `y'` are. So we can just check if the differences are equal. i.e

```
abs (x - x') == abs (y - y')
```

Putting it all together, we (hopefully) arrive at the desired function

```
isDiagonal :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Bool
isDiagonal (x, y) (x', y') = abs (x - x') == abs (y - y')
```

There's no need for `&&` here, at all. But we could use it, if for example we wanted to impose an extra condition, like the new points must be on the 4x5 board (assuming 1-indexing)

```
isDiagonal :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Bool
isDiagonal (x, y) (x', y') = x' >= 1 && x' <= 4 && 
                             y' >= 1 && y' <= 5 &&
                             abs (x - x') == abs (y - y')
```